# How do I prevent overriding a previously set property when assigning that object again?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In order words, how I maintain the value of `hasChanged` in `apiAction` while doing this?

```
let apiAction = {}

function firstFunction () {
  apiAction.form.hasChanged = true
}


function secondFunction () {
  apiAction = {
    name: 'updateBuilding',
    form: this.buildingForm,
    clearFields: true
  } // this will remove hasChanged
}

firstFunction()
secondFunction()
```

Comment: Use `Object.assign`?

Comment: Maybe use secondFunction() first, and then use firstFunction() second? You should assign the object first and then change the value afterwards.

Comment: Note that the code shown above is not syntactically correct, which makes it tricky to help you. There's nowhere *method* syntax (what you're using for those functions) and `let` are both valid in the same block.

Comment: `firstFunction` will throw an error here since `.form` is `undefined`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particularly elegant way, because `hasChanged` is a property of `form`, not `apiAction`.

You can either shallow-clone `form` and set `hasChanged` to the current value via `Object.assign`:

```
secondFunction () {
  apiAction = {
    name: 'updateBuilding',
    form: Object.assign(
            {},
            this.buildingForm,
            {hasChanged: apiAction.form && apiAction.form.hasChanged || false}
    ),
    clearFields: true
  }
}
```

(I've assumed that if `apiAction` has no `form`, or `form` has no `hasChanged`, the value should be `false`.)

...or keep the same `form` object and just set its property:

```
secondFunction () {
  if (apiAction.form) {
    this.buildingForm.hasChanged = apiAction.form.hasChanged;
  }
  apiAction = {
    name: 'updateBuilding',
    form: this.buildingForm,
    clearFields: true
  }
}
```